Changing opacity of a surface in Asymptote
Significant Edit:
The problem is local to my computer. I tested on another computer and got the desired output. Could this be a problem with a computer component such as a driver possibly?

Crosspost: https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/b178c4ae6a/
Note: When I run asymptote separately from latex on my computer, I get the desired result. (i.e. running asy on a .asy file)

I want to change the opacity of a surface in Asymptote. This seems like it should be basic, but I have flipped through the manual several times, and have checked up on the forums.
Here is my attempt:
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
unitsize(2cm);
import three;
draw(
    // I want to change the opacity of this surface so that it is translucent:
    surface((-1.5,-1.5,0) -- (1.5,-1.5,0) -- (1.5,1.5,0) -- (-1.5,1.5,0) -- cycle)
    ,surfacepen=material(
        // Setting this to 0.9 makes the surface entirely transparent, 
        // whereas any value >= 1 makes it entirely opaque.
        white+opacity(1)
    )
);
// I want to see the overlapping of the plane and these arrows.
draw((0,0,0) -- (-1,1,0), arrow=Arrow3);
draw((0,0,0) -- (0,0,-2), arrow=Arrow3);
\end{asy}
\end{document}



Test:
test.tex
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
unitsize(2cm);
import three;
draw(
    // I want to change the opacity of this surface so that it is translucent:
    surface((-1.5,-1.5,0) -- (1.5,-1.5,0) -- (1.5,1.5,0) -- (-1.5,1.5,0) -- cycle)
    ,surfacepen=material(
        // Setting this to 0.9 makes the surface entirely transparent, 
        // whereas any value >= 1 makes it entirely opaque.
        white+opacity(0.9)
    )
);
// I want to see the overlapping of the plane and these arrows.
draw((0,0,0) -- (-1,1,0), arrow=Arrow3);
draw((0,0,0) -- (0,0,-2), arrow=Arrow3);
\end{asy}
\end{document}

test-1.asy
if(!settings.multipleView) settings.batchView=false;
settings.tex="pdflatex";
defaultfilename="test-1";
if(settings.render < 0) settings.render=4;
settings.outformat="";
settings.inlineimage=true;
settings.embed=true;
settings.toolbar=false;
viewportmargin=(2,2);

unitsize(2cm);
import three;
draw(
// I want to change the opacity of this surface so that it is translucent:
surface((-1.5,-1.5,0) -- (1.5,-1.5,0) -- (1.5,1.5,0) -- (-1.5,1.5,0) -- cycle)
,surfacepen=material(
// Setting this to 0.9 makes the surface entirely transparent,
// whereas any value >= 1 makes it entirely opaque.
white+opacity(0.9)
)
);
// I want to see the overlapping of the plane and these arrows.
draw((0,0,0) -- (-1,1,0), arrow=Arrow3);
draw((0,0,0) -- (0,0,-2), arrow=Arrow3);

test.log
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)  (format=lualatex 2024.12.24)  24 DEC 2024 04:31
 restricted system commands enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
**c:/Users/twill/OneDrive/Documents/Files/Professional/GitHub/Private_Repository/Asymptote/test
(c:/Users/twill/OneDrive/Documents/Files/Professional/GitHub/Private_Repository/Asymptote/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-12-09>
Lua module: luaotfload 2024-02-14 v3.28 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 v2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 v2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended collection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/twill/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-12-28.lua" from kpse-resolved path "c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2023-12-28.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.134
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/twill/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2023/07/08 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2024/12/12 v1.0g TeX engine tests
)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count194
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count195
\c@sapage=\count196
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2022/10/10 v1.3b Default configuration file for 'standalone' class
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/twill/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count197
\c@section=\count198
\c@subsection=\count199
\c@subsubsection=\count266
\c@paragraph=\count267
\c@subparagraph=\count268
\c@figure=\count269
\c@table=\count270
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
\bibindent=\dimen140
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85/luatex85.sty
Package: luatex85 2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks19
)
\sa@box=\box52
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/asymptote/asymptote.sty
Package: asymptote 2024/02/26 v1.38 Asymptote style file for LaTeX
 (./test.pre)
\ASYbox=\box53
\ASYdimen=\dimen141
\c@asy=\count271
\AsyStream=\write3
\AsyPreStream=\write4
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2024/03/16 v1.1e Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2024/08/06 v1.4g Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2023/12/02 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 106.
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2024/04/13 v1.2e Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen142
\Gin@req@width=\dimen143
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
))
\openout4 = test.pre
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count272
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box54
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = test.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count273
\scratchdimen=\dimen144
\scratchbox=\box55
\nofMPsegments=\count274
\nofMParguments=\count275
\everyMPshowfont=\toks20
\MPscratchCnt=\count276
\MPscratchDim=\dimen145
\MPnumerator=\count277
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count278
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks21
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 485.
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
))
\openout3 = test-1.asy

<test-1.pdf, id=1, 259.97125pt x 137.49367pt>
File: test-1.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use test-1.pdf>
Package luatex.def Info: test-1.pdf  used on input line 19.
(luatex.def)             Requested size: 259.97061pt x 137.49333pt.


[1

<./test-1.pdf>] (./test.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-12-09>
 ***********
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 2457 strings out of 475554
 100000,662416 words of node,token memory allocated
 544 words of node memory still in use:
   11 hlist, 1 vlist, 2 rule, 6 glue, 4 kern, 1 glyph, 10 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 10 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:24,3:4,4:1,5:23,6:2,7:32,9:40
 25364 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 15 fonts using 723367 bytes
 72i,5n,75p,300b,233s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 13808 bytes).

PDF statistics: 11 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 5 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)

test.pdf


If it helps, these are my settings (non-minimal because I am not fluent):
{
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "notebook.lineNumbers": "on",
    "git.ignoreRebaseWarning": true,
    "editor.rulers": [72, 79],
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "lualatex",
            "command": "lualatex",
            "args": [
                "--synctex=1",
                "--interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "asymptote",
            "command": "asy",
            "args": [
                "%DIR%/*.asy"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "lualatex",
            "tools": [
                "lualatex",
                "lualatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "asymptote",
            "tools": [
                "lualatex",
                "asymptote",
                "lualatex"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.clean.temp": [
        "*.aux",
        "*.bbl",
        "*.blg",
        "*.idx",
        "*.ind",
        "*.lof",
        "*.lot",
        "*.out",
        "*.toc",
        "*.acn",
        "*.acr",
        "*.alg",
        "*.glg",
        "*.glo",
        "*.gls",
        "*.ist",
        "*.fls",
        "*.log",
        "*.fdb_latexmk",
        "*.snm",
        "*.synctex(busy)",
        "*.synctex.gz",
        "*.nav",
        "*.vrb",
        "*.tdo",
        "*.mmz",
        "*.mmz.log"
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.pdfViewer": "Adobe Acrobat",
    "latex-workshop.latex.outputDir": "%OUTDIR%"
}


I know there are a lot of TikZ people here at TeX.SE, and even some Asymptote people. I'm curious if anyone knows if this is the best forum to learn Asymptote, or if it may be preferable to cross-post on another forum as well, where Asymptote experts collect more. Is there such a forum?

I cannot reproduce the error with an opacity 0.9, I obtain what is requested. With Asymptote version 2.88 and windows10

@pascal974 Thank you for letting me know, let me check my asymptote version. Hmm... I'm on the same asymptote version, windows 10/11 too

@pascal974 Just to clarify, when you specify 0.9, it is translucent? For me it is transparent.

Okay, I ran it on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ and obtained the correct result, so my machine must be funky

I'm wondering what issues might cause this issue. I updated my ghostscript, and texlive, and even opened with adobe acrobat. What could be causing this on my system?

@pascal974 even with Microsoft Edge, it is still transparent. I am running the code in vscode locally. I would also add that I cant rotate the picture with my mouse, like I can on the ualberta website.

I can confirm the asymptote alone produces the correct result on my computer. The issue is with latex, and as it seems from @pascal974's comment, with lualatex. Is there a workaround? Thank you for identifying the problem, by the way.

Sorry, it is still transparent, even in a clean directory. I mistook opacity=1 for translucent

This forum is fine for Asymptote questions.  There is also an Asymptote discussion list (click on "Help") that I have found very helpful.

@JimHefferon Thank you for letting me know, and for informing me of this discussion list - I'll write a cross post.

Just to make sure: when you include the asy file in a LaTeX file and you change the asy file and run LaTeX, after that you then recompile the asy separately, right?

@JimHefferon I run lualatex -> asy -> lualatex every time I change the file. And I should mention that the asy command is run on test-1.asy, whereas lualatex is run on test.tex.

I can't reproduce the issue, but I do get different results with different versions of asymptote. specifically, either the viewing angle or the rendered plane differs between texlive's version of asy and a more current version.

so when exactly do you get erroneous output? when you run the lualatex -> asy loop, is the PDF produced already wrong? or do you only get an incorrect result when you include that PDF with lualatex?

@cfr the problem happens when I run asy. It generates the arrows, but the surface is transparent. When I run lualatex again, it includes the faulty image. I would mention that running asymptote regularly on my computer works fine, it is only with latex that this problem occurs.

I reran everything in a clean directory too, and am still getting the error.

but when you run asy to generate the image, that just is running it normally, isn't it? can you post the contents of the .asy files generated during the luatex compilation?

what I mean is: I don't understand the bit about it only occurring with latex involved. is the generated .asy file correct? if so, running asy on that file is exactly the same as running it on a file you write directly. don't rely on a 'recipe'. only run the compilation sequence directly at a shell prompt. and also stick to a completely flat directory structure for testing.

@cfr, I believe it is included in the post as test-1.asy. I want to mention that when I opened this file with asy, it made the correct picture, whereas when I ran asy from the command prompt, it had the issue. It literally works in the pdf too. The problem is if I have more asy environments that means.

@cfr you will have to pardon any lack of insight I may have. I just posted any information I thought was remotely relevant. I didn't know if it would be needed or not. Thank you for informing me of this, regarding the recipes.

@cfr  I tested the whole process again using the powershell in a clean directory. Running the commands manually (without recipes) yields the error. When I click on the asy file, instead of running it from cmd, it generates the correct image and that image can be loaded in the final pdf. Maybe the command is wrong?

When I run asy on the file on one computer, the file is wrong even when I open it on the computer where things are working correctly. When I run it in the same way on the computer where it is working correctly, it runs fine. The Computer where it works is newer, but the other computer has more processing power and makes documents faster.

do you have more than one version of asymptote installed? when you run asy test-1.asy does that generate a PDF? or does it generate some other format?

@cfr I have only the texlive asymptote, and it generates a pdf. Let me rerun anyways to see if there are any auxillary files generated. Edit: I can confirm that it generates a pdf, and only a pdf

@Jasper all I can suggest, I guess, is comparing the files from the 2 machines i.e. compare the .asy and generated pdfs and the versions of asy?

@cfr, the .asy files are the same, and the asy versions are the same. The pdf differs. I might reset that computer to see if that works.

you don't have a stale config file for asy somewhere do you?

@cfr I don't believe I have such a file. Besides, I have been running from the root directory
